# Firebase python read/write usage count?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I use this python code to read firestore data, but it automatic count at 3 reads on website usage page. Can you guys show me where I did it wrong:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import os
import time

cred = credentials.Certificate(str(os.path.dirname(__file__))+"/serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)



print('Initializing Firestore connection...')


# Get access to Firestore
db = firestore.client()
print('Connection initialized')

def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(u'Received document snapshot: {}'.format(doc.to_dict()['request']))

doc_ref = db.collection('user').document('com')
doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)

# Keep the app running
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    #print('processing...')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it my self, every time you do a 'write', it count as 2 reads, and 1 read come from the script, so total is 3.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).